# Codemirror AngularJS model binding break when inside bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, codemirror

I have codes as follow:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#user_interface" data-toggle="tab">User Interface</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#source_code" data-toggle="tab">Source Code</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="user_interface">
          <textarea data-ui-tinymce id="tinymce1" tinymce-modal-id="myModalTinyMCE" allow-tinymce-image="true" data-ng-model="from_one.from_one"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="source_code" >
            <div style="border-left:1px solid #DDD; border-right:1px solid #DDD; border-bottom:1px solid #DDD">
            <textarea ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions" data-ng-model="from_one.from_one">

             </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When I click on my second tab "Source Code", the content from model binding doesn't show in the code editor as picture below.
[image]
Only when I click again on the code editor content itself the data appeared:
[image]

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codemirror content not visible in bootstrap modal until it is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086538/codemirror-content-not-visible-in-bootstrap-modal-until-it-is-clicked)

Answer (score 3):

I had seen this problem, but resolved.
You can read again docs of ui-codemirror angular at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror, has one paragraph:

> " ui-refresh directive
>
> If you **apply the refresh** directive to element then **any change** to do
>   this scope value will **result to a refresh** of the CodeMirror instance.
>
> The ui-refresh directive expects a scope variable that can be any
>   thing....
>
> Now
>   you can set the isSomething in the controller scope.
>
> $scope.isSomething = true; "

So, you need change value of 'isSomething' when change tab or other action for codemirror update automatically.

For example: 
//html:

```
<tabset>
    <tab select="selectTab()" heading="Tab 1">
        <div ui-codemirror ng-model="data" ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions" ui-refresh='refresh'></div>
    </tab>
    <tab>.....</tab>
</tabset>
```

//js controller:

```
$scope.refresh = false;
$scope.selectTab = function() {
    $scope.refresh = !$scope.refresh;
};
```

Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's working you may have some problem with bootsrap.js(Add below the body) file or jquery.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#user_interface" data-toggle="tab">User Interface</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#source_code" data-toggle="tab">Source Code</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="user_interface">
          <textarea data-ui-tinymce id="tinymce1" tinymce-modal-id="myModalTinyMCE" allow-tinymce-image="true" data-ng-model="from_one.from_one"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="source_code" >
            <div style="border-left:1px solid #DDD; border-right:1px solid #DDD; border-bottom:1px solid #DDD">
            <textarea ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions" data-ng-model="from_one.from_one">

             </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, @Jangya satapathy, your code snippet above is not working, can you show me your full codes?

Comment: You have added two 'textarea' for both of the tabs, If i'm not wrong. And that is showing fine in my snippet.